# Managed BA Commandline issue

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.8

I have a BootStrapper Setup.My requirement is to display the help text of the Bootstrapper in command line

So For eg:
if I enter C:\bin\Debug>>BootstrapperSetup.exe -help and press enter my help text should be displayed .But as soon as I press enter I am getting the Commandline C:\bin\Debug>> without waiting for the help text to get displayed. It should wait for displaying the next command line until my out put is displayed.

In other words it should be

C:\bin\Debug>>BootstrapperSetup.exe -help

help text of exe

C:\bin\Debug>>

Can any one help  me on this.Thanks

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: I have overridden run method and if LaunchAction is help im using console.writeline() to print the text.Before I could print the text Im getting the next command line and help text is getting displayed in next line as given below:C:\bin\Debug>>BootstrapperSetup.exe -help

C:\bin\Debug>>  help text of exe.             

But I should get the format mentioned in my post.Thanks

Comment: The Visual Studio IDE has two programs: devenv.exe and devenv.com but that technique isn't really suitable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic Windows problem.  An exe is either compiled as a command line application or a UI application.  UI applications (e.g. WiX bootstrappers) cannot write to the console like that.  If you run msiexec /? or mstsc /?, you'll see that core Windows applications have the same limitation.